# case when wont work with update statement

Tags: mysql, sql, sql-update, case-when

For my MySQL query,

```
update Products
set new_price = (
case when change_date>'2019-08-16' then new_price=100 else new_price end
)
;
```

the update statement sets the new price to 0. why?

table details:

```
insert into Products (product_id, new_price, change_date) values ('1', '20', '2019-08-14');
insert into Products (product_id, new_price, change_date) values ('2', '50', '2019-08-14');
insert into Products (product_id, new_price, change_date) values ('1', '30', '2019-08-15');
insert into Products (product_id, new_price, change_date) values ('1', '35', '2019-08-16');
insert into Products (product_id, new_price, change_date) values ('2', '65', '2019-08-17');
insert into Products (product_id, new_price, change_date) values ('3', '20', '2019-08-18');
select * from Products;
```

Answer (score 0):

You are attempting to set `new_price` to the result of the boolean expression `new_price=100`, which will be `0` unless `new_price` already has the value `100`. Just remove the `new_price=` and the code will work fine:

```
update Products
set new_price = case when change_date>'2019-08-16' then 100
                     else new_price
                end
```

[Demo on dbfiddle](https://www.db-fiddle.com/f/oETVsyd8d3e1KyrtxhbatV/0)

Answer (score 0):

It sets the value to zero because `new_price = 100` is a boolean expression -- and that evaluates to either 0 or 1.

If this is all you are doing, you should filter in the `where` clause:

```
update Products
    set new_price = 100
    where change_date > '2019-08-16';
```